# Short story I read as a child in the early '60s, with a protagonist who looked normal in size, but was disproportionately heavy and strong

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Does anyone remember a science fiction story I read as a child in the early/mid '60s? The only thing I remember about the story was that the main character was a man who appeared to be normal in size and stature, of about 5'10 and 160 lbs., but weighed close to 500 pounds and was correspondingly stronger too.

As I recall, it was a short story, probably in an anthology, as I used to read short stories voraciously.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Was this a novel or a short story? If it was the latter, did you read it in an anthology or a magazine?

Comment: This was part of the original premise for the Luke Cage comic book character, who premiered in 1972.

Comment: Why down-vote the question.  The poster said it was all he could remember.  Now, I don't know about this story but there is an exact opposite story about a man who appeared to be morbidly obese but was actually lighter than air.

Comment: Possibly a story of a visitor from a heavy planet (high gravity)?

Comment: Hello LogicDictates, As I recall it was a short story. Probably an anthology as I used to read short stories voraciously.

Comment: Can you visit https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question and see if those prompts help you find more information to [edit] in? Like do you think this was in a book? A magazine? Comic book?

Comment: Well, there's the very strong Pippi Longstocking, but she wasn't a man.

Comment: @EmsleyWyatt *The Truth about Pyecraft* by Wells.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This *could* have been a story by John Campbell. The description *not quite* fits that of Aarn Munro, a native of the Jupiter colony. Adapted to a gravitational pull more than twice Earth, Aarn has much denser bones and more powerful muscles (as well as being a superman in almost every other regard), and is able to lift both his sidekicks Spencer and Carlisle with one arm:

> Jupiter, a world with two and a half times the gravity of Earth,
> required strength in its people, and speed, too.
>
> On Earth, Aarn weighed nearly three hundred and fifty pounds. For the
> first twenty years of his life he had lived on the giant of the system
> and had developed such strength as no Terrestrian ever dreamed of.
> More than once he had proved his ability to lift and walk off with a
> ton and a half of lead.
> [ *The Mightiest Machine*, Astounding, 1934-1935 ]

Comment: Thank you LSerni, but I don't think he was an alien. I think he was of this planet but somehow transformed. Also,I'm positive it was a short story.

Comment: @donkoerner Aarn Munro is *not* an "alien" -- he is the son of an Earth scientist marooned on Jupiter, and was born and grew there until he was about twenty. This made him an incredibly strong human.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification LSerni. I see that the book "Incredible Planet" is actually three novelettes combined. This may be why I considered it to be a short story. I think Aarn Munro is my guy.